# SQL: How to parse string with repeated characters?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, parsing

I want to parse the column `value` and generate the `output` column. The issue is that I will need to start from the right to parse the output. How do I parse through repeated characters?

```
| value                          | output    |
|--------------------------------|-----------|
| ABC - DEF - 0100 - 0100 - 0100 | ABC - DEF |
| GHIJ KLM - 0100 - 0100 - 0100  | GHIJ KLM  |
| NOPQR - 0100 - 0100 - 0100     | NOPQR     |
| STU-VWXYZ - 0100 - 0100 - 0100 | STU-VWXYZ |
| ABD                            | ABD       |
```

```
CREATE TABLE #CHAR (value VARCHAR(MAX), output VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #CHAR VALUES
('ABC - DEF - 0100 - 0100 - 0100', 'ABC - DEF')
,('GHIJ KLM - 0100 - 0100 - 0100', 'GHIJ KLM')
,('NOPQR - 0100 - 0100 - 0100', 'NOPQR')
,('STU-VWXYZ - 0100 - 0100 - 0100', 'STU-VWXYZ')
,('ABD', 'ABD')

SELECT * FROM #CHAR
```

Accepted Answer

```
SELECT t.*,
CASE WHEN t.value LIKE '%-%' THEN LEFT(value, PATINDEX('% - [0-9]%', value))
    ELSE t.value
    END
FROM #CHAR t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `LEFT()` and `PATINDEX()`:

```
select t.*,
       left(value, patindex('% - [0-9]%', value))
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87036da2546f10c319bd0e6df22949fd) is a db<>fiddle.